# Is there any way to add site notice a disposable message in a google site using any google sites api programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, google-apps-script, google-sites

I am looking for a way to add Site notice‎ - a disposable message in a site using google sites API with a service that will be responsible for adding the site notice message to the selected site. So do we have any such Google Sites API to add it programmatically using C# or with any Google Apps Script?

Basically we can add this message manually by going to the below google site settings page.

{Google_Classic_Site_Url}/system/app/pages/admin/settings

Below is the screenshot for reference:

[image]

And the working result is below:

[image]

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. You might start searching at https://developers.google.com and in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites

Comment: Yes, I did research on google for this specific api and even checked the google sites api in the https://developers.google.com/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol#ContentFeedGET but didn't find the api. Please suggest if any.